# I keep getting errors for my restaurant code?

Tags: python, string, list, append

So basically idk I just feel like my code is not really getting anywhere. I have trouble with the list and stuff, and I need this for school. My teacher doesn't really teach, and this is what they 'taught' us so far about list arrays, but I don't really understand it. Also, I keep getting this error of:

```
TypeError: append() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given) on line 31
```

My is alright, the printing turns out OK. I took out my whole menu here and just pasted where my problem occurs. Here's the part that actually works though:

```
print "[Welcome to Python Cafe!]"
print ('\n')

print "1) Menu and Order"
print "2) Exit"
choice=input("What would you like to do? ")

print ('\n')
if choice == "1":
        print "-T H E  M E N U-"
        print " DRINKS "
        print "1. Coffee: $2.50" 
        print "2. Hot Cocoa: $2.30"
        print "3. Tea: $1.50"
        print " FOOD "
        print "4. Bagel: $1.50"
        print "5. Donut: $1.00"
        print "6. Muffin: $1.50"
```

The main problem is in the `while` statements and `if` statements, and how it 
doesn't print my order in the end. I already tried changing my code, for example:`if order == "coffee":` to instead `if order == "1":` so I could make it easier so user doesn't have to type out the whole word? And also I tried taking out the `tot=tot+...` just to see. I have no idea, my teacher just told us to do that, but I don't think this format is quite right.

```
    if choice == "1":
        print ('\n') 
        food=[]
        order=0
        while order != "done":
            order=input("What's your order?  ")
            if order == "coffee":
                    list.append("coffee")
                    tot=tot+2.50
            else: 
                if order == "hot cocoa":
                        list.append("hotcocoa")
                        tot=tot+2.30
                if order == "tea":
                        list.append("tea")
                        tot=tot+1.50
                if order == "bagel":
                        list.append("bagel")
                        tot=tot+1.50
                if order == "donut": 
                        list.append("donut")
                        tot=tot+1.00
                if order == "muffin":
                        list.append("muffin")
                        tot=tot+1.50
        print ('\n') 
        print "Here's your final order:"
        for item in food:
            print(order)
```

And when the `append()` error doesn't appear, and the code actually 'works' when I change it back, it just ends there after 'done' and doesn't print anything after. I'm sorry if this seems really confusing, I just think this whole code is a mess.

Comment: Just type `food.append(...)` everywhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the `list.append()` method *unbound*. `list` is the built-in type, and `.append()` is the method that when used on *list instances* would let you append values to that list. But you haven't told `list.append()` what list instance to append to.

You'd normally call methods *on the specific list instance*:

```
food.append("coffee")
```

That's still the same `list.append()` method, but now it is *bound*, to the `food` list instance, and Python then makes sure that `list.append(food, "coffee")` is called. You'd not normally use `list.append()` directly (for one, it would prevent subclasses from overriding the `append()` method), leave it to Python to figure out the correct binding here.

Do this everywhere you use `list.append("...")` now.

You are also printing out the wrong variable in your 'here is what you ordered' loop:

```
for item in food:
    print(order)
```

and you never gave `tot` an initial value; you have `order=0` there but you also use `order` to store the customer input! You probably got `order` and `tot` confused there.

For each item in the `food` list, you want to print `item`, not the last thing the customer ordered:

```
for item in food:
    print(item)
```

or, if you want to be really slick and impressive, use some advanced Python syntax and print the whole list with newlines in between in one step with:

```
print(*food, sep="\n")
```

You probably want to define a mapping from food items to prices, using a dictionary:

```
prices = {
    "coffee": 2.50,
    "hot cocoa": 2.30,
    "tea": 1.50,
    "bagel": 1.50,
    "donut": 1.00,
    "muffin": 1.50,
}
```

That makes it much easier to check for correct orders, and to add more items to menu in future! Now you can just use:

```
tot = 0
food = []
while True:
    order = input("What's your order?  ")
    if order == 'done':
        break
    if order not in prices:
        print("Sorry, we don't have any", order)
    else:
        food.append(order)
        tot = tot + prices[order]

print("Here is your order:", *food, sep="\n")
print("That'll be", tot)
```

Note how I snuck in an extra message for orders you don't have prices for. Also, the above adds `"hot cocoa"`, not `"hotcocoa"` to the `food` list, do take that into account if that might be a problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
list.append("coffee")
```

should be

```
food.append("coffee")
```

and this should be everywhere in your code wherever you are using `list`. `list` is a built-in type in Python

---

Also, the following code (the last loop to print items)

```
     for item in food:
        print(order)
```

should be

```
    for item in food:
        print(item)
```

else it will just print the last entered order by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Merely an answer but the formatting is better.
Just type:

```
food.append(...)
```

instead of

```
list.append(...)
```

everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Replace `list` with `food` which to append into

Replace `order` with `tot` which to save price into

Replace `final` order with `item` which to print items